# Error: Discard position id too big

Tags: r, shiny

Does anyone know how to resolve the following errors in the `shinyserver.log`

```
[33m[2017-10-05 21:38:28.591] [WARN] shiny-server - ESC[39mError handling message: Error: Robust protocol error: Expected CONTINUE message
ESC[33m[2017-10-05 21:39:35.380] [WARN] shiny-server - ESC[39mError handling message: Error: Robust protocol error: Expected CONTINUE message
ESC[33m[2017-10-05 21:42:00.858] [WARN] shiny-server - ESC[39mError handling message: Error: Discard position id too big
ESC[33m[2017-10-05 21:42:12.854] [WARN] shiny-server - ESC[39mError handling message: Error: Discard position id too big
ESC[33m[2017-10-05 22:07:44.000] [WARN] shiny-server - ESC[39mError handling message: Error: Discard position id too big
ESC[33m[2017-10-05 22:07:44.846] [WARN] shiny-server - ESC[39mError handling message: Error: Discard position id too big
ESC[33m[2017-10-05 22:08:14.373] [WARN] shiny-server - ESC[39mError handling message: Error: Discard position id too big
ESC[33m[2017-10-05 22:08:16.561] [WARN] shiny-server - ESC[39mError handling message: Error: Discard position id too big
```

I believe it's related to the application constantly disconnecting from the server

Comment: There was already something similar reported
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/q6eyj_6hPJw

Comment: I don't think these two items are related

Comment: Well this seems to be some sort of socket error. Try restarting your instance(server) or add more memory so it can communicate properly,as it looks like it stops responding to requests

Answer (score 2):

This hasn't completely alleviated  the problem, but it has helped immensely.  I moved these values out from 60 and 5 to 360 and 1800 respectively.

[3.3 Application Timeouts](http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#application-timeouts)

> Each Shiny Application has two timeouts associated with it:

---

> app_init_timeout -- Describes the amount of time (in seconds) to wait
>   for an application to start. After the specified number of seconds has
>   elapsed, if the R process still has not become responsive, it will be
>   deemed an unsuccessful startup and the connection will be closed. The
>   default value for app_init_timeout is 60 seconds.

---

> app_idle_timeout -- Defines the amount of time (in seconds) an R
>   process with no active connections should remain open. After the last
>   connection disconnects from an R process, this timer will start and,
>   after the specified number of seconds, if no new connections have been
>   created, the R process will be killed. The default value for
>   app_idle_timeout is 5 seconds. Typically, these two parameters will be
>   correlated. Shiny Applications that involve little processing to start
>   (therefore have a small app_init_timeout) can often be closed with
>   minimal concern (and thus would have a small app_idle_timeout).
>   Conversely, applications that require a substantial amount of data to
>   be loaded on startup may merit a longer app_init_timeout to give the
>   data time to load, and a longer app_idle_timeout as the task of
>   spawning a new process is more expensive and should be minimized.

Comment: As sidenote, this only happen if you use shiny server. In our project we have new stack and we use docker with swarm (multiple instances of same app + load balancer with traefik) and we don't need shiny server so there is no timeout (we also don't have any messages in console).