# Application failed to start on shiny web server after a few days

Tags: r, nginx, shiny

I have a running shiny app on a web server that worked fine until I would say last week. Now, on occasion (I guess every two days) the app stops working with the *"Application failed to start"* message. When I restart the shiny server, as I did just now, everything runs fine again.

[image]

https://butterlab.imb-mainz.de/flydev/

The funny thing is, I have other apps on this server as well, and they are not affected and run fine in parallel, even if this app failed.

I can not find any error message in the log files. And I am wondering: how I could debug this, since the app is now running fine?

Looking forward to any advice.

**EDIT:**
I checked the `shiny-server.log` file after the error occurred and I found the following message:

```
[2018-06-14 14:29:20.080] [WARN] shiny-server - RobustSockJS collision: MqU4rgur76RPgjJIPr
[2018-06-15 01:28:18.398] [WARN] shiny-server - Error handling message: Error: Discard position id too big
[2018-06-15 02:00:10.358] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application took too long to respond.
[2018-06-15 02:00:10.364] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application took too long to respond.
```

The last message gets repeated whenever someone accesses the server.

Comment: Have you looked at these [answers/comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597718/error-discard-position-id-too-big)?

Comment: I found this answer this morning and changed it accordingly. So I guess I have to wait now for a few days and see if the error appears. But I would love to have additional debugging options :-(

Comment: Did you go through [this page](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/debugging.html)?

Comment: Hm, the `options(shiny.trace = TRUE)` options seems to be interesting, I will switch it on and have a look!

Comment: I just solved an issue with a Shiny App which constantly ran into an error on start-up by adding the file `restart.txt` in the top directory of the app. On UNIX-alike systems `touch restart.txt` will create or update the timestamp of this file.

Comment: @Uwe So it is just a plain txt file? Have you some documentation why this works?

Comment: Please see http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#restarting-an-application

Comment: @Uwe so this means you `touch` this file once a day? As far as I understood I still need to touch it at some interval?

Comment: @drmariod, no, I `touch restart.txt` only if I recognize that the Shiny App does not start up properly. What happend after you touched it? Do you get different messages in the log file? Does the `RobustSockJS collision` message re-appear?

Comment: @Uwe For me, this made the `RobustSockJS collision` disappear. You made my day, I hat this issue recurring for months! ty!

Answer (score 1):

So in the end, it seems this page solved my problem [Error: Discard position id too big](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597718/error-discard-position-id-too-big)

I set `app_init_timeout` and `app_idle_timeout` both to `1800`and since then I have no further problems.

Also the comment with the `restart.txt` file might be interesting. I thought about testing with a shell script if the page is still working, otherwise touching the txt.
http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#restarting-an-application

But as I said, in the end it works by adjusting the `app_init_timeout` and `app_idle_timeout`.